# How to encrypt saved password in firefox?

Tags: windows, linux, security, firefox

In our company we are using one pc for everything. Everybody is using firefox and a lot of people are using the *save password* option. I know that you can easily read the username/password with the firefox password manager. Is there a solution restrict this? Maybe an option to encrypt the data, or a firefox addon? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Set a [master password](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Master_password):

[[image: Screenshot of master password option]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYaJy.png)

> Using a master password is not selected by default; you will need to set one in the Password Manager, as explained below under Setting a master password. You can view using a master password as a way to authenticate who you are to the Software Security Device, just as you do with a server on a web site: you log into a web site and enter your credentials and you do the same if supplying the master password.
>
> If you supply the Master Password in the popup window that you see if a master password is needed, then you log in to the Software Security Device (Firefox uses: "Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Encryption: Certificates: Security Devices: Software Security Device"). If you select the Software Security Device then you notice an enabled "Log Out" button if you are logged on, otherwise the "Log In" button is enabled in that window. Access to the encrypted names and passwords is possible as long as you are logged on to the Software Security Device and you need to log out to prevent others from accessing that data if you leave your computer unattended. "Tools > Clear Private Data : Authenticated sessions" does the same, but also additionally will log you out of secure web sites. You may need to clear the cookies to log out of other sites.

**Just remember the master password applies to the profile, so each person would need their own [Firefox profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_Manager).**

At the end of the day, the password database is available to anyone who has physical access to the system. Even encrypted databases can be cracked, especially if the master password is a weak one (generally, the longer the better, and no dictionary words).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Rohos Mini Drive Portable (portable utility) allows to use encrypted partition on any PC without Admin rights, without install.
Thus storing your data on a flash drive. Nobody will be able to use your data